# how to convert a Dictionary with multiple values for a single key in multiple rows to single row with multiple values to a key

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, key

Below is my requirement. Below is the data that is present in json file:

```
{"[a]":" text1","[b]":" text2","[a]":" text3","[c]":" text4","[c]":" Text5"}.
```

The final output should be like

```
{"[a]":[" text1","text3"],"[b]":" text2","[c]":" text4"," Text5"]}.
```

I tried below code:

```
data_in= ["[a]"," text1","[b]"," text2","[a]"," text3","[c]"," text4","[c]"," text5"]
data_pairs = zip(data_in[::2],data_in[1::2])
data_dict = {}
for x in data_pairs:
    data_dict.setdefault(x[0],[]).append(x[1])
print data_dict
```

But the input it takes is more in form of List than a dictionary.

Please advise.

Or is there a way where i can convert my original dictionary into list with multiple values as list will take only unique values. Please let me know the code also i am very new to Python and still learning it. TIA.

Comment: That's an invalid dict. You cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: dictionary keys are unique, while duplicate keys are *valid in dictionary literals*, however, that will evaluate to a dict where the right-value entry is kept. `{'a':1,'a':2,'b':3} == {'a':2,'b':3}`

Comment: like @Rakesh told it's an invalid dict . So you can change the dict like keys as values and values as keys.

Comment: Thanks everyone. the dictionary i defined is the one present in a json file. Instead of giving all the values in that file, i have given a subset.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks. how do i convert keys to values and values to keys? this makes sense as values are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are unique within a dictionary while values may not be.

You can try

```
>>> l = ["[a]"," text1","[b]"," text2","[a]"," text3","[c]"," text4","[c]"," text5"]
>>> dict_data = {}
>>> for i in range(0,len(l),2):
    if dict_data.has_key(l[i]):
        continue
    else:
        dict_data[l[i]] = []


>>> for i in range(1,len(l),2):
    dict_data[l[i-1]].append(l[i])

>>> print dict_data
{'[c]': [' text4', ' text5'], '[a]': [' text1', ' text3'], '[b]': [' text2']}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Harsha for this. but, you have taken list as the input. If i take that, the code i mentioned above already works. My question is how to take the dictionary as the input. Or atleast convert the dictionary i mentioned above into the list, the one taken as input.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, Keys are unique within a dictionary. {'a':1,'a':2,'b':3} == {'a':2,'b':3}

Comment: How do i convert the dictionary i mentioned into the list? the one which you used as input.

Comment: You cant make a dictionary containing same key twice.

Comment: The dictionary that i defined, is the data that is coming from a json file. The data in json file contains in the same format. How can i convert that json file into list without losing the multiple values? that should solve the problem. As you said and others too, dictionary cannot contain duplicate keys, but list can i think, right? then how do i convert that data into list with the duplicate keys?

Comment: Appreciate if any one can help me to resolve this or suggest me a proper approach to this problem. this is my first scenario in Python. TIA.